# Can you use a part of string, read from text, as a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, file, parsing, variables

I am trying to parse some text from files (about 200 files) into an app but I want some of the text to get result from variables. Here is an example.
I got a file called "Description.txt".

The text in the file is this one "Put #{@number} mines with #{@damage} damage."

```
@number = 3
@damage = 5
@text = File.read("Description.txt")

####When I print the variable I want to get this
echo @text

"Put 3 mines with 5 damage."
```

Is it possible?

Comment: So your class is having all the instance variables defined for all the 200 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@text = "This is what's in my file. Put #{@number} mines with #{@damage} damage. How now, brown cow?"
```

```
@number = 3
@damage = 5
regex = /Put #{@number} mines with #{@damage} damage./
@text[regex]
  #=> "Put 3 mines with 5 damage."
```

beginning at offset

```
$~.offset(0).first
  #=> 27
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will do! Here is another way with Sub I just found!

@text.sub! '#{@number}', "#{@number}"
@text.sub! '#{@damage}', "#{@damage}"